# Ordenar por data e nome ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, classificação

estou usando o "Comparator" para ordenar minha listview. Ordenar apenas 1 elemento, está funcionando, porém com dois o mesmo não funciona.

```
 //ordenar por data
                        arrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator<Vagas>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Vagas o1, Vagas o2) {
                                return o2.getDataAtualizacao().compareTo(o1.getDataAtualizacao());
                            }
                        });
```

E logo abaixo dele estou tentando ordenar por nome

```
    //ordenar por nome
                        arrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator<Vagas>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Vagas o1, Vagas o2) {
                                return o1.getNome().compareTo(o2.getNome());
                            }
                        });
```

Teoricamente não era para ele ordenar por data e logo em seguida ordenar por nome?

Se eu deixar apenas ordenando por nome ou por data, ele ordena normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Teoricamente não era para ele ordenar por data e logo em seguida
>   ordenar por nome?

Simultaneamente não. Desta forma no qual está fazendo, como está usando o método `sort` no mesmo *adapter*, apenas prevalecera uma ordenação, que seria a ultima.

Fazendo uma adaptação [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805676/2570426), usando 2 strings, deves ficar desta forma abaixo, como por exemplo ordenar um *array* qualquer através do Nome e Sobrenome. Veja:

```
arrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator <Vagas> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(Vagas o1, Vagas o2) {
        String x1 = ((Vagas) o1).getNome();
        String x2 = ((Vagas) o2).getNome();
        int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

        if (sComp != 0) {
            return sComp;
        } else {
            String y1 = ((Vagas) o1).getSobrenome();
            String y2 = ((Vagas) o2).getSobrenome();
            return y1.compareTo(y2);
        }
    }
});
```

**Obs.:** Como também que o método `getDataAtualizacao` pelo nome seria uma data, então deve-se fazer o tratamento caso não esteja no formato `Date`. No exemplo acima, seria mesmo comparação em strings. Já para este seu caso, deves estar em formato `Date`. Veja:

```
Date y1 = ((Vagas) o1).getDataAtualizacao();
Date y2 = ((Vagas) o2).getDataAtualizacao();
```

Comment: Tem alguma forma de fazer essa ordenação, usando o mesmo adapter? Ou teria que buscar outra coisa para fazer? Se puder citar eu agradeço para poder buscar e aprender

Comment: @Flávio corrigi os probleminhas que estavam, veja agora se funciona corretamente e me fale.

Comment: ele chega a executar porém ele cai no `if( sComp !=0)` , então ele ordena apenas por nome. Se eu trocar para `if (sComp == 0)` ele ordena por data